# Using Terraform for every region in a given account, find all VPCs and for each VPC enable flow logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, terraform, provisioning

In Terraform how to populate the list of VPC IDs into the map. 
I want to find all VPCs for every region in a given account and for each VPC enable flow logs.How this can be done using Terraform

Answer (score 1):

There's an example to do exactly this in the [AWS provider documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpcs.html), something like:

```
data "aws_vpcs" "foo" {}

resource "aws_flow_log" "test_flow_log" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids)}"
  ...
  vpc_id = "${element(data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids, count.index)}"
  ...
}

output "foo" {
  value = "${data.aws_vpcs.foo.ids}"
}
```

This would only cover one region, (whatever region you've configured in the provider), to do multiple regions, you need to instantiate [multiple providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#multiple-provider-instances), one in each region:

```
# The default provider configuration
provider "aws" {
  # ...
}

# Additional provider configuration for west coast region
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-2"
}
```

It then would make sense to create a module for your flow log resources and then [pass in each provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#passing-providers-explicitly) like so:

```
# The default "aws" configuration is used for AWS resources in the root
# module where no explicit provider instance is selected.
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"
}

# A non-default, or "aliased" configuration is also defined for a different
# region.
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "usw2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

# An example child module is instantiated with the _aliased_ configuration,
# so any AWS resources it defines will use the us-west-2 region.
module "example" {
  source    = "./example"
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.usw2"
  }
}
```

You would then repeat the module instantiation for the provider in each of the regions.